# Attach attachments to multiple records?

Tags: apex, attachment, bestpractice, file-storage

Is there any way to attach Notes or Attachments to multiple records?

I had originally thought that the Attachement.Body field was a pointer to the location of an attachment, and I would be able to have multiple attachments referencing the same File... but I think I was wrong.

Not sure if there's any way around this, or a best practice for dealing with this.

Comment: Would it be against the rules in your business process to make another copy of the attachment for each of the other records? or do you only want to have a single instance of the attachment in the org and then have the single attachment referenceable from the multiple records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't link multiple attachments, but you can link a single Chatter File to multiple objects via the Chatter Sharing model, and the Chatter Attachments will appear in the Attachment Related List

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to attach a single Note or Attachment to multiple records. The `ParentId` field is the field which specifies what record the Note or Attachment is attached to.